# jdbi: Use @MapResultAsBean annotation together with CustomMapperFactory

Tags: java, postgresql, orm, dropwizard, jdbi

I can map a result from a jdbi query to the bean of my interest using `@MapResultAsBean` annotation as below:

```
@SqlQuery("select * from some_table where id = :some_id")
@MapResultAsBean
SomeBean findById(@Bind("some_id") String someId);
```

This works fine if the `jdbi` instance used in application is not already registered with any custom mapper.

But the application that I am working upon has a custom mapper as below:

```
class CustomMapperFactory implements ResultSetMapperFactory {
    // Override methods to provide custom conversion logic
}
```

This mapper is registered with the `jdbi` instance at the start of the application as below:

```
final DBIFactory factory = new DBIFactory();
final DBI jdbi = factory.build(environment, conf.getDatabase(), "postgresql");
jdbi.registerMapper(new CustomMapperFactory());
```

`CustomMapperFactory` overrides methods and provide logic to convert *any* type of result from database to relevant bean type. It is just this one uber converter that takes care of all DB to POJO conversions throughout the application.

My question is:
*Is there a way that I can somehow tell `jdbi` to keep using this `CustomMapperFactory` for converting result from database to bean of all types except of type `SomeBean`.*

I tried adding `@MapResultAsBean` having `CustomMapperFactory` still registered with `jdbi`. The program runs, but the custom mapper registered with `jdbi` takes precedence and the `@MapResultAsBean` has no effect at all and is just ignored.

Couldn't find much about it on internet. Any help? We use `dropwizard-jdbi-1.2.2` and apparently `postgres` database.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a couple of ways:

a. Tell JDBI that your `CustomMapperFactory` doesn't map the type `SomeBean`. This way, JDBI will fall back to using `@MapResultAsBean`:

```
public class CustomResultMapperFactory implements ResultSetMapperFactory {

    @Override
    public boolean accepts(Class type, StatementContext ctx) {
        if (type == SomeBean.class) {
            return false;
        }
        //....
    }
}
```

or

b. Explicitly return `BeanMapper` for the `SomeBean` type:

```
public class CustomResultMapperFactory implements ResultSetMapperFactory {

    @Override
    public ResultSetMapper mapperFor(Class type, StatementContext ctx) {
        if (type == SomeBean.class) {
            return new BeanMapper(type);
        }
        // ..
    }
}
```

Note that in this case, you don't need to have the `@MapResultAsBean` annotation.